# How to bind dynamic data?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding, datagrid

I have a set of data that contains over 3000 fields. 
I don't want to manually create a class and property for each field.

Is there a way I can create rows of dynamic objects and bind them to the list.

Everything I have tried has failed and i'm not sure its possible using bindings.

Its funny how someone marked the question down yet no one knows the solution.

Comment: As a user I can foresee some problems with being displayed a table of information 3000 columns wide.  I work with some that are just a few hundred and I consider them excessive.

Comment: Ok, it was a "slight abbreviation" more like 186 fields to be exact but I don't want to create a class with 186 properties.

Comment: What format is the data in now?

Comment: What I do is select all the required fields from a Database then parse some delimitered strings to construct the data. So each row is a string array.

Comment: Would ExpandoObject help here? Or a custom implementation of one?

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now but for GridView I use a List<string[]> and then in the ctor I create as GridViewColumn for each column and bind it to string[i].  Or you can use a DataTable and DataGrid.

Comment: I thought it would too Matt :(

Comment: No one knows a solution?  That is how I do it and it is in a commercial application.

Comment: Sorry Blam, Missed your comment. I have tested your theory and it works thank you. You didn't post as an answer so I cannot accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you used my comment and to post.

I don't have access to the code right now but for GridView I use a List and then in the ctor I create as GridViewColumn for each column and bind it to string[i]. Or you can use a DataTable and DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this same problem with dynamically built tables. With some research I came up with a solution that was able to handle a varying amount of fields. Its made up of two classes.

First there is a property class, look at this as a column in the table.

```
 public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }//field name
    public object Value { get; set; }//value
    public Type DataType { get; private set; }//datatype if needed
}
```

Then, you have a Record Class - which is essentially a collection of Property objects. Look at this is a single row in a table.

```
public class Record : INotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    private ObservableCollection<Property> _Properties;
    public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties
    {
        get { return _Properties; }
        set
        {
            _Properties = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Properties");
        }
    }

    public Record(List<Property> properties)
    {
        _Properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();

        foreach (var property in properties)
            _Properties.Add(property);
    }

    public Record(List<Property> properties)
    {
        _Properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();            

        foreach (var property in properties)
            _Properties.Add(property);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    //protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    //{
    //    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    //    if (handler != null)
    //    {
    //        handler(this, args);
    //    }
    //}

}
```

Then you can bind this what would essentially be a collection of Records to whatever control or item you needed to.

Comment: You have the same ctor twice.  Please post an example of how you to bind a collection of Records to a control.  How is the control going to know to build the columns?

Comment: I bound to it but its just giving me a list of [Collections] names on each row instead of the actual results.
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Records, ElementName=context}">

Comment: I just gave you the framework... It kind of depends on your business domain, how you get the data what you do with it.

Comment: Sorry don't see how it would work in this instance or any instance in dynamic binding.